# "Unable to resolve superclass/Link of class failed" errors with Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I'm getting these errors when trying to use an external library imported (as a Maven file dependency) through the Project Structure > Dependencies window in Android Studio 1.0 RC 2:

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/melnykov/fab/FloatingActionButton$1; (1487)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/melnykov/fab/FloatingActionButton$1;' failed
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "user.appname"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
}
```

I've googled around and most solutions are for projects in Eclipse, involving setting the Java Build Path to Order and Export, but I can't seem to find a similar setting in Android Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you added

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to your `build.gradle`, I think that your issue is caused by gradle not being able to reach **external resources**.
Are you behind a proxy?

I solved this problem adding file `gradle.properties` in my home .gradle directory. It's made like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=myproxy.mydomain.it
systemProp.http.proxyPort=myproxyport
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myproxyuser
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=XXXXXXXX

systemProp.https.proxyHost=myproxy.mydomain.it
systemProp.https.proxyPort=myproxyport
systemProp.https.proxyUser=myproxyuser
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=XXXXXXXX

systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```